# Adding a custom namespace to XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I am trying to add my own namespace to my xaml file in order to use my own class easily -I guess  the reason is this-
I wrote the following code in window tag for this:

```
xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:LibNameSpace"
```

Where my window tag also starts with the following definition:

```
<Window x:Class="LibNameSpace.MainWindow"
```

I want to use the `LibNameSpace:Class1` class, and I was hoping to write `myns:Class1` for this. However, that command causes this error:

> Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'LibNameSpace' that is not included in the assembly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure to add the library reference to the application project

Answer (score 35):

The name LibNameSpace sounds like its a library in another assembly. If this is the case, you must add the name of the assembly:

```
xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:LibNameSpace;assembly=MyLibAssembly
```

**Update:**

The name of the assembly can be found in project-explorer in the properties-screen of the project (of the library-assembly). In general also the file-name of the dll without the `dll`-suffix represents the assembly name.

Comment: well, in deed i saw such a solution from somewhere but i didn't know from where to learn the name of my assembly...=)

Comment: Any other suggestion/ idea/ help??

Comment: i am afraid it doesn't work when i write  xmlns:myns="clr-namespace:LibNameSpace;assembly=LibNameSpace"

Comment: Does your Assembly name contain any spaces? You should add a underscore for spaces I guess.

Comment: it's funny that when i tried to write the full name such as "clr-namespace..." by hand it didnt work but when i just picked the namespace from the intellisense list, it worked...
thanks for help=)

Answer (score 10):

Because for me it's not really clear what you want to do, here another try:

If `MyLibAssembly` is the main namespace of your application and there in you have a Window named `MainWindow` and a class named `Class1` that you want to instantiate in your `MainWindow`-class:

- Make sure, that in Class1 is no
  error, the project must 
  compile without errors. Remove first the
  namespace-declaration from the xaml and compile your
  project till you have no compilation errors.
- Make sure that Class1 is public and
  has a paramterless constructor
- Make sure that in the code behind
  your MainWindow is also in the
  `MyLibAssembly`-namcespace.
- Add then the namspace-declaration
  `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LibNameSpace`
  into your xaml. `local` is generally
  used to declare the same namespace as your current element, in your case the window, is in.
- Insert your `Class1` with the
  `<local:Class1/>` -tag in the xaml. If Class1 does not derive from FrameworkElement or a higher level control, you must add it into the resources-section of your window. If this is true, give it a key. `<local:Class1 x:Key="KeyToYourClass"/>`

Maybe vs is out of sync. Click in the solution-explorer on the root-node **Clean Solution** and then **Rebuild Solution**. Maybe that helps.

I hope this helped. If not, try to reformat your question (use the code-symbol to make the question more readable and try to rephrase to make more clear what your desire is).

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to rebuild. I was getting really frustrated with the persistent squiggly.

Comment: from UserControl.xaml, the issue is to delete the standard file:UserControl.xaml.cs\vb; then have the happening under a file MyClass.cs\vb where MyClassNamespace.MyClassControls.UserControlClass works like UserControl.xaml.cs\vb

Answer (score 6):

Use Intellisense. In my case one space mattered. instead of

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataAccess;assembly=DataAccess"
```

I hand typed

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataAccess; assembly=DataAccess"
```

Notice the space after `';'`. This made the difference. So use visual studio Intellisense and it will render you correct xaml markup.

Comment: Tried so many different things and this one finally did it! So simple

Answer (score 5):

I found this answer while I was struggling with problems in Windows 8. I was trying to use a User Control and I had several errors. The last ones where:

> Error 9   Cannot add 'ScrollControl' into the collection property 'Children', type must be 'UIElement'

and:

> Error 10  Unknown type 'ScrollControl' in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:EventTests.Controls;assembly=EventTests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

ScrollControl is my user control.

I ended up replacing this:

```
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:EventTests.Controls"
```

For this:

```
xmlns:Controls="using:EventTests.Controls"
```

I hope this saves the time I spent with this issue.