# "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock" when IValueConverter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding text,Converter={StaticResource visibleconvert}}"
           Foreground="Black">
</TextBlock>
```

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
    string str = (string)value;
    string[] strList = str.Split('=');

    Run run2 = new Run();
    run2.Text = strList[1];
    SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    run2.Foreground = mySolidColorBrush;
    txt.Inlines.Add(run2);
    return txt;
}
```

As results is **"`Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock`"**. I had debugger then return `txt` is `null` while **"`txt.Inlines.Add(run2);`"** is having data. Everyone help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using a MultiValueConverter by sending the TextBlock itself to the converter. refer below code

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <local:TextBlockConverter x:Key="Conv"/>
</Window.Resources>

 <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Conv}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Mode="OneTime"/>
                <Binding Path="senselist" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>

class TextBlockConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TextBlock txt =  values[0] as TextBlock; 
        string str = (string)values[1];
        string[] strList = str.Split('|');
        Run run1 = new Run(strList[0]);
        run1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        Run run2 = new Run(strList[1]);
        Hyperlink hyp = new Hyperlink(run2);
        txt.Inlines.Add(run1);
        txt.Inlines.Add(hyp);
        return txt;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

 senselist = "sense_list" + "|" + "gramGroup";
```

My post [Bold,Inlines, hyperlink collections of textblock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700377/bold-inlines-hyperlink-collections-of-textblock/29701178#29701178)

Comment: I modified my solution using a Multivalueconveter.